# Using private framework generated by RuntimeBrowser in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-privateapi, xcode7.3

I have generated all the private framework API's using RuntimeBrowser and I add them to my test project in Xcode.

I just did an import of the "RadiosPreferences.h" header file and try a build with several errors.  Please see attached screenshot.

I'm having some problem understanding how I can add the AppSupport.framework and specifically use methods in the RadiosPreferences header file.  If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

[image: build failed]

Answer (score 1):

**First lets start by how to link those frameworks**

lets assume you want to use SpringBoardServices framework

1. go to https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/ and download the headers
2. search for **SpringBoardServices.framework** folder and copy all headers inside
3. go to */Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework* 
   and create a folder named **Headers**

> replace **iPhoneOS.platform** with **iPhoneSimulator.platform** an paste the headers in simulator SDK folder too if you want to try apps on the simulator

4. paste the files you just copied inside

> Now you can link the SpringBoardServices Framework

**Now how to use SpringBoardServices**

```
#include <SpringBoardServices/SpringBoardServices.h>
void openMailApp(){
    SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier(CFSTR("com.apple.MobileMail"), false);
};
```

this will open the mail application

```
SBSCopyNowPlayingAppBundleIdentifier();
```

to get the name of the app that currently playing music